# is there any way to let the other user know that i have joined the voice call channel in agora?

Tags: react-native, call, agora.io

I am using agora in react native for voice and video calls but I didn't find any method in agora to let the other user know that I have joined the channel and now he should also like some sort of incoming call to another user

Answer (score 0):

in `IRtcEngineEventHandler` interface we have a function named  `onUserJoined (int uid, int elapsed)`

It invoke whenever a new user joined the call.

For more detail, read here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html?platform=Android#aa466d599b13768248ac5febd2978c2d3

Comment: this function call occurs when the other user joins the channel but what I want is that when I join channel the channel the other user gets a call like in WhatsApp so that he can also join the channel hope you understand my question

Comment: for that you need to send notification.

Comment: how can i send notification only to specific user? is there any function for that in agora?

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but I found this and planning to integrate but I'm using Android not sure if you can use any of the other platforms since I noticed there is no React Native for the Signaling sdk.

https://docs.agora.io/en/signaling/develop/call-invitation?platform=android